# A way to sort out inputs according to the order they are inputted?

Tags: c++

So I am working on a program that takes an infix expression and converts it to a postfix expression. Meaning when I input a+b, the output will be ab+, And i cant figure out a way to print it out correctly because I cannot think of a way to sort the letters, like how can i translate the input a+b-c to ab+c- instead of abc+-? Source code is still in progress.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int prec(char in)
{
    switch(in) {
        case '(': return 0;
        case '+': 
        case '-': return 1;
        case '*': 
        case '/': return 2;
        default : return 3;
    }

}

int main()
{
    stack <char> ops;
    //stack <char> high-ops;
    char next_character ;

    while(!cin.eof()) {
        cin >> next_character;

        if(next_character =='(' )
            ops.push('(');
        else if(next_character == ')') {
            while(!ops.empty() && ops.top() != '(') {
                cout << ops.top();
                ops.pop();
            }
            if(!ops.empty())
                ops.pop();
            else
                cout << "Error/n";
        }
    if((next_character >= 'a' && next_character <= 'z') || (next_character >= 'A' && next_character <= 'Z') || (next_character >= '0' && next_character <= '9')) 






    if(next_character == '*' || next_character == '/' || next_character == '+' || next_character == '-') {
        if(ops.empty())
            ops.push(next_character);
        if(prec(next_character) > prec(ops.top()))
            ops.push(next_character);
        if(prec(ops.top()) > prec(next_character)) {
            cout << ops.top();
            ops.pop();
            if( prec(ops.top()) == prec(next_character)){
                ops.push(next_character);
                cout << ops.top();
                ops.pop();
            }
        }
    }   
        //if(!ops.empty())
            //ops.push(next_character);

}   
while(!ops.empty()){
    cout << ops.top();
    ops.pop();  
}
```

}

Comment: Your `prec` implementation is wrong - `+` and `-` should have the same precedence, same as `*` and `/`.

Comment: Sorting has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with this process. This is about converting infix format to postfix. This is typically done by implementing a recursive-descent parser, rather than a stack-based approach. Although implementing a stack-based approach is also possible, a recursive-descent parser is a far simpler solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need recursive parsing, not a stack based one.

In psuedo code, it would look like this:

```
func reorder(expression)
    if whole_expression_is_wrapped_with_parentheses
        return reorder(expression without wrapping parentheses)
    if exists_operator(expression)
        oi = operator_index = find_operator(expression)
        before = expression.substring(0 to oi-1, including)
        operator = expression.charAt(oi)
        after = expression.substring(oi + 1 to end of string)
        return reorder(before) + reorder(after) + oi
    return expression

func exists_operator(expression)
    Simply check if any operator is in the expression out of parentheses.

func find_operator(expression)
    Return the id of the first operator found out of parentheses.
    To implement precedence, ignore lower precedence operators until making sure no higher precedence operators are in the expression
```

The two helper functions should be implemented with a stack-based parentheses counter, to make sure you search only out of any parentheses.

Comment: It can. But it doesn't need. I don't like this answer because it's all about things you think. Also the brain-stormy napkin notes are likely to be useful to no one outside yourself, let alone the OP who was already so confused to think arriving at the infix notation was a sorting task.

Comment: @sehe Which napkin notes?